# VS Code project structure not matching IntelliJ and Repo

Tags: vs-code, sourcecontrol, illuminatedcloud, intellij

I joined a team who do not like to use VS code as it doesn't match the source GIT and their IntelliJ IDE's do.

Is there any way to "fix" this in VScode?

VS Code: Showing content under the normal default / lws

[image: VSCode]

IntelliJ (and the repo) showing content under src

[image: IntelliJ]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix this because the format in the repostiory is the old metadata format which [is not supported in VS Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/source-format/).

> Because legacy tools such as Force.com IDE **used the metadata format,
>   you can’t directly open your such projects in VS Code**. You must either
>   convert your metadata to source format (using sfdx
>   force:mdapi:convert) or create a new project and then retrieve the
>   metadata from your org using the manifest (package.xml file) that you
>   used in your previous IDE.

The question you should ask them is why they don't update their repository to the source format which IntelliJ/Illuminated Cloud also supports. This would allow the developers to choose their tool as well as be better suited for source control development as highlighted by the documentation. If you're using source control, your repository should be in the source format.

> The commands that Salesforce Extensions for VS Code uses to push,
>   pull, deploy, and retrieve your source assume that your files are in
>   source format (rather than metadata format). **Source format is
>   optimized for working with version control systems.**

You can utilize the CLI to convert projects pretty easily with:

`sfdx force:mdapi:convert`

And then pushing all the changes to your repository.